# mysql - fetching data from table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have gotten a snippet of code to bring back the username and password and see if they match.  i now want to set a session varaible to the 'points' value i have in the table which is in the same row as the username and pass.. what could be done?

```
    <?php $username="asdin";
$password="1sdA2";
$database="a75sdting";
$pword = $_REQUEST['pword'];
$uname = $_REQUEST['uname'];
mysql_connect('mysqsdst.com',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `username` WHERE `password` = '$pword' AND `username` = '$uname'");
$exsists = 0;

        WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $exsists = 1;
         break;
         }
            if ($exsists){
            $_SESSION['usern']=$uname;
            $_SESSION['logged']=1;

            header('Location: http://wwsdipts/logged2.php');


                    }



mysql_close();

 ?>
```

i want to set $_SESSION['points'] = $row[points] i guess... but i dont think that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// start session (required on every page that uses sessions
session_start();

// db auth
$username="asdin";
$password="1sdA2";
$database="a75sdting";

// user auth
$pword = $_POST['pword']; // should use either $_POST or $_GET, NOT $_REQUEST
$uname = $_POST['uname']; // should use either $_POST or $_GET, NOT $_REQUEST

// open db connection
$conn = mysql_connect('mysqsdst.com',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die( "Unable to select database");

// check user
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `username` WHERE `password` = '$pword' AND `username` = '$uname'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
    // user exists
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION['usern']=$uname;
    $_SESSION['logged']=1;
    header('Location: http://wwsdipts/logged2.php');
}else{
    header('Location: http://wwsdipts/login.php'); // take them back to login page if incorrect details
}

// close db connection
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

I've tidied up your code a bit, please take a look at the notes. It is also worth nothing the following:

1. You should be using some sort of protection against SQL injections, such as `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname'])` - the same for password
2. You need session_start() on all pages that use session variables
3. You shouldn't use $_REQUEST, use either $_POST or $_GET (read about it)
4. Do you actually have a table named `username`? You should read up a bit about DB design, a better name/use for this table would be users as the table will be holding users (a combination of unique ID, username & password.
5. I don't know what you mean about points, but to access any column name in the "username" table, use `$row['column-name']` after it is set (`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);`)
6. If you intend on using PHP a lot in the future, you should look up PDO, it's a great class for handling SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you are right, but in this case your array is `rows`, and it should be in

```
$_SESSION['points'] = $rows['points']
```

And it should be in your `while` loop:

```
    WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $exsists = 1;
     $_SESSION['points'] = $rows['points']
     break;
     }
```

However, it might be better to do something like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
  //Login Successful
  rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $_SESSION['points'] = $rows['points']
  $_SESSION['usern']=$uname;
  $_SESSION['logged']=1;

  header('Location: http://wwsdipts/logged2.php');
}
```